# Backbone models and plain objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm writing a javascript library (in coffeescript) that works as a frontend for a non RESTfull API. Basically what it does is it defines classes for my resources that make the API calls and massages the data it gets back so I can have nice and clean objects.

Now, I want to use this library in a Backbone based project but also without backbone (maybe in NodeJS).

The easiest way to use it with Backbone would be to pass the objects I create with this library to the Backbone model constructor so it populates the Backbone models with the attributes from the objects. The only problem is that these objects also have functions on them so those will get attached to the model's 'attributes' object aswell which I'm not really happy with. In this scenario if I have a function called 'doStuff' on my object I'll end up 
calling model.attributes.doStuff() and I'm not sure that makes a lot of sense.

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe a way to have my library create either plain objects or Backbone models by passing a configuration option?

Answer (score 2):

I would detach the data associated with your objects so that they are not direct properties, and then add getters/setters for that data object.

```
var myObject =  {
    var data = { .... the data ... };
    var get = function() { return this.data; }
    var set = function(value) { this.data = value; }
};
```

You can then create Backbone models like this.

```
var x = new myObject();
var model = new Backbone.Model(x.get());
// ... work with model
x.set(model.attributes);
```

Alternatively, you can link the Backbone model with the same data reference.

```
var x = new myObject();
var model = new Backbone.Model();
model.attributes = x.data;
```

Sorry if the above isn't correct Javascript, but you should be able to get the idea.

**EDIT:**

You can include a reference to `myObject` as a second parameter to model, but you'll have to create your own model class. (based upon latest Backbone version).

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    /**
     * @type {myObject}
     */
    obj: undefined,

    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
       this.obj = options.obj;
    }
});

var x = new myObject();
var model = new myModel(x.get(),{obj:x});

// now you can use Backbone model normally
model.set('field',123);
// call your own functions
model.obj.foo();
```

Comment: And what about the functions I have implemented on myObject? I won't be able to call them from the model.

Comment: @NickDima see my edit, but now that I think about it. I don't see the benefit. Backbone is really easy/popular. Why not just use that and not create this extra layer?